# Is there a way for a class that implements IDisposable to throw an exception if it's not been instantiated via a using block?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I spotted some potentially dangerous classes that would be much less dangerous if they couldn't be instantiated unless they were done so within a using statement.

I'm wondering if there's a way to force the classes to only be instantiated in that way.

(I'm aware what the IL compiles out as which is why I'm not massively sure this is even possible)

Cheers,

Phil.

Comment: I'd suggest writing a class that hooks up to an electric device placed under developers that don't clean-up after themselves. You can then implemente a finalizer that checks if dispose was called, and if not, electrocutes the developer. I think it's called pavlov reflex induction.

Answer (score 13):

There's no way to enforce it, but you can probably build a [custom Code Analysis rule](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/) to flag it.

Comment: FxCop and Nitriq can also be used for this kind of rule enforcement.

Comment: This is the best suggest I've seen. I thought you could enforce Code Analysis on a per-solution basis. Is that not correct?

Comment: @Jaxidian - I'm not sure about the solution level, I know you can run CA when building per project. But it outputs warnings. You can [enforce CA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667398(v=vs.90).aspx) during check-ins when using Team System.

Comment: @Jaxidian - Looks like the solution settings just set the project level properties for CA.

Comment: That being said - there are times when you explicitly don't want to dispose of an object immediately.  Sometimes you need to store it, and in those cases, this will potentially give a false positive.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be a custom rule. CA2000, CA2202 and CA2213 already cover this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182289.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182334.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182328.aspx

Comment: @Tatham - Those are probably the way to go, but don't flag instances where an IDisposable object is instantiated outside of a user statement.

Comment: @Tatham - Oops, meant "instantiated outside of a using statement".

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no way to have the compiler enforce this.  It would be dangerous to do so, in any case, as there are times you want to use `IDisposable` classes in other fashions, such as encapsulating them within a second `IDisposable` class impelementation, etc.

If your class is implemented properly, then the destructor should clean up any unmanaged, undisposed resources.  This is less than ideal, but still can work.

One good option is to have the destructor raise an exception or log during debug.  This can help you track, during testing and debug time, any "missed" cases of using an `IDisposable` improperly.

Comment: +1 for the notifications during debug.  I found that logging the stack trace at construction helped track down where the offending object was created and so often where it should have been disposed.

Answer (score 5):

For all effective purposes it is impossible. Especially since it doesn't have to be a `using`, someone could have written out the `try{}finally{}`. You could make sure anything unmanaged was properly disposed of in the finalizer.

Comment: I'd not trust the developers in question to handle that properly everytime - thus the reason I'm after enforcement.

Comment: @Phil: There's no way to have the compiler do it, but there are potential ways to trap it prior to deployment.

Comment: @Phil then I think you need better developers, as it's sometimes more convenient to just use `try{}catch{}finally{}` than `using{try{}catch{}}` or `try{using{}}catch{}` when you're going to have a catch block anyway.  Also more handy if you need to do something in addition to disposing in the finally block.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this would make your object only usable within local scope. That means you couldn't safely store it in a class field, for example.

Although you can't force the client to write the `using` statement, you can encapsulate the resource in a method that does use the `using` statement. This would be your resource code:

```
public sealed class Resource : IDisposable {
  private Resource() { }
  public void Dispose() { ... }
  public void Use(Action<Resource> action) {
    using (var resource = new Resource()) {
      action(resource);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, client code is forced to use the `Resource` through its `Use` method:

```
Resource.Use(resource => { 
  // use the resource...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such way, as the `using` statement is syntatic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want this, although it seems like a good idea.  This would mean that your instances can only have local scope, and that you can't pass the disposable objects to other methods, or use them as field variables in your class.

What you should do is implement the [dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx) in your class, so that they are cleaned up correctly.

A trick that I have seen used (and indeed used myself) is to note the call stack during object construction, then have a Debug.Assert in the destructor which notifies the developer of the call stack when the object was created.  This helped a lot in tracking down where the non disposed object had come from and so helped find the place where the object responsible for the disposal was not doing so.  Something along these lines (I don't have access to the code I used so this is my current best guess, YMMV):

```
private StackTrace m_stackAtConstruction;
private bool m_disposed;

public Constructor()
{
     m_stackAtConstruction = new StackTrace();
     m_disposed=false;
}

public void Dispose() 
{
    Dispose(true);

    // Use SupressFinalize in case a subclass
    // of this type implements a finalizer.
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);      
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // If you need thread safety, use a lock around these 
    // operations, as well as in your methods that use the resource.
    if (!m_disposed)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            if (_resource != null)
                _resource.Dispose();

        }
        else
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Object not disposed correctly - Stack trace at construction was " + m_stackAtConstruction.ToString());
        }

        // Indicate that the instance has been disposed.
        _resource = null;
        _disposed = true;   
    }    
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't always work, in small programs the garbage collector can skip using the finalizer completely.

Comment: You can test this behavior in a small console app, that only makes a single instance of the disposable class. And i'm sure it is mentioned somewhere on the `MSDN` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[CA2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182289.aspx), [CA2202](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182334.aspx) and [CA2213](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182328.aspx) cover this via static code analysis. Just configure these rules to result in errors and you'll get a compile time failure. Why even wait until runtime for an exception?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really - that would be really intrusive to developers. What I think you are looking for is a static analysis tool, like FxCop, to ensure disposable objects are properly disposed.